# Can i install .NET Core 2.2 SDK alongside Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core

I currently have Visual Studio 2012 and I want to download .NET Core SDK (https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/thank-you/dotnet-sdk-2.2.103-windows-x64-installer).

I don't want to use it inside the VS2012 because I know this is not possible.

My question is if I can have and use .NET Core alongside VS2012? It will be safe to install the SDK? Or it might affect the functionality of VS2012 somehow?

I can't install another VS version on my PC and I want to try .NET Core.

Comment: it wont impact vs2012

Comment: Yes! You can! There will be no problem! To use .NET Core 2.2 You have to just install VS2017 or VS2019

Comment: @TanvirArjel or use Visual Studio Code ;)

Comment: U can't it alongside VS 2012

Comment: @MindSwipe Yeh! That's too :)

Comment: @MindSwipe exactly what I've wanted to say, I can't install VS2017/2019 so I will use Visual Studio Code.

So I guess it's ok to install the SDK alongside VS2012?

Comment: @leo_acm94 yes go for it! It may take some getting used to because VS Code is not an IDE but an extensible Text Editor so you'll have to do some more manual work than in something like VS2017 but it teaches you a lot about how the build process works and lets you peek under the hood. Also [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/csharp) is a great resource about getting started developing C# in VS Code with some great extension recommendations

Comment: @MindSwipe thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, it is totally possible to install .NET Core 2.2 alongside Visual Studio 2012. You wont be able to create .NET Core 2.2 Projects using Visual Studio 2012, for this you need at least Visual Studio 2015 Update 3.3 or later.

If you're looking for an alternative, Visual Studio Code might be interesting to look at. [Here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/csharp) is a tutorial to working with C# in VS Code and [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/other/dotnet) is a simple step by step tutorial to creating a "Hello World" console app in .NET Core and VS Code